# How to show the whole source code of load more page after clicking on load more botton?

Tags: html, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, web-inspector

I have a problem with this  [page](https://sabq.org/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%85%D9%84%D9%83%D8%A9/%D8%A5%D9%82%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%AF)!

when entering it, you can right-click and view the source code via, say, chrome and see the articles with their links..etc. However, when pressing on "المزيد" and viewing the source code again, the source code of the new articles does not appear. Only the source code of the previous articles does.

What would you recommend to solve this problem?

I have pressed on view page source code on google chrome, but nothing appeared regarding the new articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *View source* option only shows the source code of a page as it was delivered from the server. It does not take modifications performed using JavaScript into account.

The button mentioned in your question loads more content and inserts it into the page programmatically using JavaScript.

**You need to use the *Elements* tab of Chrome Developer Tools to see programmatically inserted HTML code.** Right-click anywhere on the page and choose "Inspect", or press Ctrl+Shift+I or F12 on Windows. (Shortcuts on other platforms may vary.)